# Saving a program and loading a program in use

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that moves a little man forward by walking or running etc.
I need to be able to save the state of the little man and load it at any given time and I have no idea how to do this. Could anyone please help me get the ball rolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have the state (the position of the character, maybe something else) stored in some sort of Python data structures. You could create a file storing this information. The most obvious ways are:

1. Create a plain-text file with text/numbers needed to recreate the state. You will need to parse it to load the state, but you can choose any file format you like.
2. Use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to dump your Python objects to a file directly. You will then read them using `pickle.load` and won't have to bother parsing the file.